# Center component inside the material-ui grid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to use same cards and make them center aligned, I searched and tried some solutions but all of them align only the component grid, and not the component content itself (I need them to be equally distant form the borders and from themselves).

[image]
[image]

I'm using this code (https://codesandbox.io/embed/32o8j4wy2q):

```
<Grid
      container
      spacing={0}
      direction="column"
      alignItems="center"
      justify="center"
      style={{ minHeight: '80vh' }}>
      <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={8}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Card />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Card />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Card />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Card />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

The card code is irrelevant but I just copied the material-ui's example one.

Also, how do I use flexboxes (or other tool) to auto align if I decide in the future to add or remove some cards?

Comment: have you tried to remove "inside container" ? or move `alignItems` and `justify` to it ?

Comment: @Maielo I tried all of these. I made a CodeSandbox to help the visualization and tests https://codesandbox.io/embed/32o8j4wy2q

Comment: I would add `margin: auto` to the inner `div` wrapping the content. I couldn't fork your demo but adding this to the CSS _seemed_ to work: 

`div[class^='MuiGrid-item-'] > div { margin: auto; }`

Comment: @Teknotica I tried it and it didn't work for me, I tried placing it inside the grid item and later, placing it in the container too. Did you removed some parameters?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I soved it by adding `align="center"` in the JSX code that means `align-items: center` in CSS as explained [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/6013).

The code was done like this:

```
  <Fragment>
    <Grid
      container
      spacing={24}
      justify="center"
      style={{ minHeight: '100vh', maxWidth: '100%' }}
      >
     <Grid item xs={3} align="center">
        <Card />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3} align="center">
        <Card />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3} align="center">
        <Card />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3} align="center">
        <Card />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Fragment>
```

Comment: I got a strange result with this. It works but then the app crashes and tells me there is no overload for that call. Did you do anything else besides adding that?

Comment: This method can lead to an error where there is no overload for the grid component, in this  case you can place a Grid container with alignItems="center" as @Invaraid suggested.

Answer (score 4):

The `align` props does not exist anymore with grid. We can compose with `Grid` and `Box`

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid xs={8} item>
    <Box
      height="100%"
      display="flex"
      justifyContent="center"
      flexDirection="column"
    >
      Content with smaller height
    </Box>
  </Grid>
  <Grid xs={4} item>
    Content with bigger height
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer did not work for me, I got an error indicating that there was no overload for grid with an Align prop. I instead wrapped the component I wanted center aligned in a Grid container, with `justify="center"` and `alignItems="center"`.

So in OPs example, it would look like:

```
<Fragment>
<Grid
  container
  spacing={24}
  justify="center"
  style={{ minHeight: '100vh', maxWidth: '100%' }}
  >
    <Grid item xs={3} align="center">
       <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center">
          <Card />
       </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think using a Box component can handle it too: https://material-ui.com/system/flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<Fragment>
    <Grid container spacing={24} justify="center" style={{ minHeight: "100vh", maxWidth: "100%" }}>
        <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ textAlign: "center" }>
            <Card />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ textAlign: "center" }>
            <Card />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ textAlign: "center" }>
            <Card />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ textAlign: "center" }>
            <Card />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Fragment>;
```

sx={{ textAlign: "center" }} is  used to apply the center alignment styling to a specific JSX component or HTML element within a React application.

Answer (score 0):

To align the Grid item content into it's centre

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid xs={8} item
      display="flex"
      justifyContent="center"
      flexDirection="column">
    <Box>
      Content with smaller height
    </Box>
  </Grid>
  <Grid xs={4} item>
    Content with bigger height
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```