# How to centre Material-UI Grid Components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

> This post has been resolved

Hi, I'm using Material-UI in my React App, and I want to centre a Grid item that contains a Card and two more Grid items.
Here is the relevant code. The Cards do appear in the middle of the screen, but they aren't centred and it's really, *really* annoying me.

Screenshot:

[image]

Necessary code:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom>
            My Projects
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} justify="center">
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Card>
              <CardMedia
                component="img"
                height="140"
                image="https://github.com/dbarnes18/Portfolio/blob/master/assets/images/spotter.png?raw=true"
                alt="Spotter"
              />
              <CardContent>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                  Spotter
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                  Spotter is an easy-to-use Spotify music controller with
                  functioning room and voting systems.
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
              <CardActions>
                <Button
                  size="small"
                  color="primary"
                  to="/project/spotter"
                  component={Link}
                >
                  Read More
                </Button>
              </CardActions>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <br />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Card>
              <CardMedia
                component="img"
                height="140"
                image="https://github.com/dbarnes18/Portfolio/blob/master/assets/images/impulse.png?raw=true"
                alt="Spotter"
              />
              <CardContent>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                  Impulse
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                  Impulse is a macOS Virtual/Voice Assistant!{" "}
                  <i>Impulse is a little buggy and slow.</i>
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
              <CardActions>
                <Button
                  size="small"
                  color="primary"
                  to="/project/impulse"
                  component={Link}
                >
                  Read More
                </Button>
              </CardActions>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
```

**Some system info:**

```
Google Chrome: 93.0.4577.82 (Official Build) (x86_64)
Revision: e3a25d9b9e2d0b728e045ec87c0aa4942aa46e4e-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#1237}
OS: macOS Version 10.15.7 (Build 19H1417)
JavaScript: V8 9.3.345.19
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center component inside the material-ui grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364157/center-component-inside-the-material-ui-grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say using material-ui

just add style to your code

material-ui v4.12.3

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItem: "center"
  }
}));
```

and add it to your Grid

```
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
           ....
)}
```

[check out here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-3-zlpdd)

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest answer it's to a div with name of `.container` and give it `width:100%` and `display:flex;justify-content:center;gap:20px` and that's it.

here preview : https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-bird-ulpvm?file=/index.html